# Roles not working properly in Spring security

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I am working on a spring security based web application in which I want to limit the items on the side bar based upon whether the logged in user has role ADMIN or USER. As far as authentication is concerned, everything is working fine but roles are not working as expected.

[Following this post](https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-web-application-part-6-spring-security-with-dao-authentication-provider/)

For example -

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
            <li class=" nav-item"><a href="<c:url value = "/mapview/list"/>"><i
                    class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span class="menu-title" data-i18n="">MapView</span></a>
            </li>
            </security:authorize>
```

The above element never gets visible even though I log in as - ADMIN.

Can someone please help me here in understanding what is going wrong.

Security Config

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {


        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/resource/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin").successForwardUrl("/postLogin").failureUrl("/loginFailed").and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/doLogout").logoutSuccessUrl("/logout").permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }


}
```

UserDetailsImpl

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Boolean enabled = true;

    public void setAuthorities(Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
```

UserDetailsService

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    private Converter<User, UserDetails> userUserDetailsConverter;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "userToUserDetails")
    public void setUserUserDetailsConverter(Converter<User, UserDetails> userUserDetailsConverter) {
        this.userUserDetailsConverter = userUserDetailsConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userUserDetailsConverter.convert(userService.findByUserName(username));
    }
}
```

UserToUserDetails

```
@Component
public class UserToUserDetails implements Converter<User, UserDetails>{
     @Override
        public UserDetails convert(User user) {
            UserDetailsImpl userDetails = new UserDetailsImpl();
            if (user != null) {
                userDetails.setUsername(user.getUsername());
                userDetails.setPassword(user.getEncryptedPassword());
                userDetails.setEnabled(user.getEnabled());
                Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
                });
                userDetails.setAuthorities(authorities);
            }
            return userDetails;
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
@SessionAttributes({ "currentUser" })
@Controller
public class HomeController {
  //skipping other mappings
@RequestMapping(value = "/postLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postLogin(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext().getAuthentication();
        validatePrinciple(authentication.getPrincipal());
        String username = ((UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        model.addAttribute("currentUser", username);
        return "redirect:/dashboard";
    }

}
```

[image: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication in controller]

User

```
@Entity
public class User extends Auditable<String> {

//skipping other details
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Tables created in db-

```
user
role
user_role
```

**EDIT 1**

Just added this mapping inside my controller and Once I login, if i hit /test on browser, both the booleans show **false**. I have no idea why the roles are not being set.. :-(

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public void test(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper request) {
        boolean b = request.isUserInRole("ADMIN");
        System.out.println("ROLE_ADMIN=" + b);

        boolean c = request.isUserInRole("USER");
        System.out.println("ROLE_USER=" + c);
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

But, at the same time, below code shows role as ADMIN

```
public void test(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper request) {

        for (GrantedAuthority authority : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()) {
            String userRole = authority.getAuthority();
            System.out.println(userRole);
        }
    }
```

[image: Admin Role]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like information is getting lost somewhere between retrieval from database and returning a response to the browser (obviously). Good thing you have a debugger, so I would start by tracing each step from where you access your database data, until you return that information. Follow every single step until you find where is it being lost, and post back when you have narrowed it down to a single place. If not maybe we can start looking at your html/script/template engine, but only after we are sure info is reaching browser.